# Errno::ENOENT No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen sinatra wont load views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra

i have a view in the /app/views/users/signup.html and am calling erb :"users/signup.html" but am getting this error and it seems like sinatra cant find my views folder.

Comment: You're going to need to include a lot more detail. Can you show us the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify views folder like this

```
set :views, Proc.new { File.join(root, "templates") }
```

Documentation: http://sinatrarb.com/configuration.html

I suppose that you should storeviews like`/views/users/signup.html` - without `app` folder